# splitting string in Python (2.7)

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7

I have a string such as the one below:

```
26   (passengers:22  crew:4)
```

or

```
32   (passengers:?  crew: ?)
```

. What I'm looking to do is split up the code so that just the numbers representing the number of passengers and crew are extracted. If it's a question mark, I'd look for it to be replaced by a "".

I'm aware I can use string.replace("?", "") to replace the ? however how do I go about extracting the numeric characters for crew or passengers respectively? The numbers may vary from two digits to three so I can't slice the last few characters off the string or at a specific interval.

Thanks in advance

Comment: *The numbers may vary from two digits to three* is contradicted by your example; I see a *one* digit number there (`4`). My answer assumes that 1 digit is fine too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks Martijn. The examples given are only two out of hundreds of strings. There could be an entry for 'crew:135' for example.

Comment: Yes, and that's 3 digits. `4` is *one* digit but you then go on to say that the numbers vary from two to three digits, which would mean that `4` is not a valid number.

Comment: Ah ok apologies.... Yes the numbers would indeed vary from 1 to possibly numbers in their hundreds. Apologies and thanks for the solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A regular expression to match those would be:

```
r'\(\s*passengers:\s*(\d{1,3}|\?)\s+ crew:\s*(\d{1,3}|\?)\s*\)'
```

with some extra whitespace tolerance thrown in.

Results:

```
>>> import re
>>> numbers = re.compile(r'\(\s*passengers:\s*(\d{1,3}|\?)\s+ crew:\s*(\d{1,3}|\?)\s*\)')
>>> numbers.search('26   (passengers:22  crew:4)').groups()
('22', '4')
>>> numbers.search('32   (passengers:?  crew: ?)').groups()
('?', '?')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Appreciated.